# Kerberos says there is no KDC at my server's location while getting initial credentials

Tags: kerberos

This is probably some stupid error I've overlooked, but I've been working on this on and off for about a week.

Running version 1.10.3 release 17.fc18

This is my krb5.conf

```
[logging]
default = FILE:/var/log/krb5libs.log
kdc = FILE:/var/log/krb5kdc.log
admin_server = FILE:/var/log/kadmind.log

[libdefaults]
default_realm = KERBEROS.INTERNAL.COM

[realms]
KERBEROS.INTERNAL.COM = {
   default_domain = kerberos.internal.com
   kdc = kerberos.internal.com:
   admin_server = kerberos.internal.com:
}
```

I know the DNS is working correctly

```
$ host kerberos.internal.com
kerberos.internal.com has address 10.8.0.1
```

And the server is running

```
krb5kdc.service - Kerberos 5 KDC
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/krb5kdc.service; enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2013-06-25 21:42:07 EDT; 10min ago
```

But this still happends

```
$ kinit -V kadmin/admin
Using default cache: /tmp/krb5cc_0
Using principal: kadmin/admin@KERBEROS.INTERNAL.COM
kinit: Cannot contact any KDC for realm 'KERBEROS.INTERNAL.COM' while getting initial credentials
```

And this

```
$ kadmin -p kadmin/admin
Authenticating as principal kadmin/admin with password.
kadmin: Cannot contact any KDC for requested realm while initializing kadmin interface
```

Is it just some stupid mistake, or did I screw up the installation or something? I've messed around with DNS options a bit, and I don't think they make much of a difference. It is definitely accepting connections, and the journal shows absolutley nothing.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is likely the hanging colons at the end of the kdc line.

```
kdc kerberos.internal.com:
```

Either get rid of the colon or add the port that the kdc is running on.

```
kdc kerberos.internal.com:88
```